# what kind of data structure to use, and how to iterate over it

Tags: c#

Say my data looks like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
  SubKey1:SubValue1
  SubKey2:SubValue2
Item 4
  SubKey1:SubValue1
Item 5
  SubKey1:SubValue1
  SubKey2:SubValue2
  SubKey3:SubValue3
```

Is there a data structure that supports this or would I need to create a new type?

Comment: This is not descriptive enough, what is each item? A primitive? An object? Additionally, how do you want to access each item and sub-item? Do you want to iterate through the collection, index the collection, or use a hash value like a string?

Comment: Agree with above comment. Maybe a JSON object? Need more info...

Comment: No, JSON would add too much overhead. There are a lot of types of C# data structures that support what the OP wants, it's just a matter of him being more specific before a more specific answer can be provided.

Comment: Yes I'd like to iterate over it, so trying to figure out the easiest way to do that. They're all strings.

Comment: Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>

Comment: @Sunny wouldn't using that restrict me to only one "SubKey/Value pair" per Item?

Comment: Write a `class` that reflects the above structure, simply. (Although more info could lead to a more precise answer.)

Comment: @Drew, `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>` is a list of key value pairs, the key being a string, the value being a dictionary which can have multiple key/value pairs itself.

Comment: new Dictionary<string,string>(){ "item3", new Dictionary<string,string>() { {"SubKey1", "SubValue1"}, {"SubKey2", "SubValue2"} } };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything that you want is a string, you could use this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

You would use it like this:

```
var myItems = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

myItems.Add("Item 1", null);
myItems.Add("Item 2", null);

var subDictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
subDictionary1.Add("subKey1", "subValue1");
subDictionary1.Add("subKey2", "subValue2");
myItems.Add("Item 3", subDictionary1);

var subDictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
subDictionary2.Add("subKey1", "subValue1");
myItems.Add("Item 4", subDictionary2);

var subDictionary3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
subDictionary3.Add("subKey1", "subValue1");
subDictionary3.Add("subKey2", "subValue2");
subDictionary3.Add("subKey3", "subValue3");
myItems.Add("Item 5", subDictionary3);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my purposes. Credit to Sunny too!

Comment: Indeed, credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty nebulous question.

However, this sounds like a List of Dictionary objects:

```
class MyItem : Dictionary<KeyType,ValueType> {
    string MyItemData1;
    int MyItemData2;
}
```

Then, just have a list of your items:

```
List<MyItem> ItemList = new List<MyItem>();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you could use a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

In the first two items you could just have an empty dictionary (or a null).

But it depends a bit on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct item
{
   public string Id;
   public Dictionary<string,string> MyValues;
}
```

Then create a list of item

```
List<item> myItemList = new List<item>();
```

Comment: He mentioned everything was a string, no need to create a struct in that case.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a list of [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)s to me

```
public class SomeClass 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ChildValues {get;set;}
}

var myItems = new List<SomeClass> { 
 new SomeClass { Name = "Item 1"}, 
 new SomeClass { Name = "Item 2"}, 
 new SomeClass { 
                  Name = "Item 3", 
                  ChildValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
                         { 
                           new KeyValuePair("SubKey1", "SubValue1"), 
                           new KeyValuePair("SubKey2", "SubValue2") 
                         } 
                }

};

foreach (var item in myItems) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
  if (item.ChildValues != null) 
  {
      item.ChildValues.Each(i=>Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:{1}", i.Key, i.Value);
  }
}
```

this is off the top and untested, but i think it will be close

Comment: This is ... a lot of overkill. Also, why do you have a `List<KeyValeuPair<string, string>>` ... you do realize that's the exact same thing as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, just more inefficient?

Comment: yeah, it's probably more explicit than necessary, but it isn't clear how the data is to be used.  this ensures the relationships are *very* clearly defined